# Sharepoint don't get JSON with IE9

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, internet-explorer, json, angularjs, asmx

I have a small AngularJS Application in SharePoint 2013, where I get a JSON File from an asmx WS to show. The Application runs fine, except with IE9 on SharePoint. All other Browser don't have any problems and the App is working.

Strange is, when I run the App with IE9 on IIS, then the App is working aswell. So somewhere an issue between IE9 and SP. The WS will not be called, so no data in the console log.

Can anybody help me ?

This is my get request:

```
app.controller('test2', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {


$http.get("/test.asmx/GetDataJSON", 

  {
    params: {
        format: "json",
        cache: false,
        async: false
      }

  })
  .success(function(data){
      $scope.data = data;
      console.log($scope.data);    
});}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of your `console.log` call.. In IE9 and lower the console object is undefined unless the browser dev tools are open.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and your hint. Has anyone other hints to solve the issue above ? Still struggling with this...